# get row and column and depth based off element number

Tags: matrix

Is there a way to represent a 3D array in a single array. 
How would I find the depth?

I know that I can have a single array that can represent a 2D array by using:

```
column = (int)(index / width)
row    = index % width
```

meaning these are the same:

```
index:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8      //width = 3;
         -----------------
element: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 

  0 1 2
 ------
0|9 8 7  
1|6 5 4 
2|3 2 1
```

to get the row and column represented by the index in the array.

I know that I can use a 2D array and use the row and column trick as a single array representation, and then use the other array as the depth level.

I was just curious if there was a simple mathematical relation based on the index, just like the row and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 3D matrix like this:

```
int matrix_3D[d][h][w];
```

then it can be represented as a flat matrix like this:

```
int matrix_flat[d * h * w];
```

The equivalent to accessing the element at

```
matrix_3D[i][j][k]
```

would be:

```
matrix_flat[(i * h * w) + (j * w) + k]
```

Conversely if you have a flattened index `index` then you can get back to the three separate indices using:

```
i = index / (h * w);
j = (index / w) % h;
k = index % w;
```